# Solution for Storage Access API Using Angular (Request Storage Access)

Tags: angular, request, storage

Is there a solution for iframes where you're able to get cookies from a site within an iFrame so that they carry through to the next page?
I see this Request Storage Access, here =>
https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/

Does anyone have any solutions based on Angular?

Thanks